# Trying to bubble sort data from file in an array, cant get it to sort. Just keeps displaying in its original order

Tags: c++, arrays, file, sorting, bubble-sort

I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have tried everything I could think of, I have searched the internet for solutions, I just can not get it to work. Starting to lose my mind a bit.

I have another issue with in my second function with my file. Not sure why, but it's making me open the file within the function, even though I already opened the file in the first function.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

//function prototypes
void openFile(ifstream &inFile);
void displayNumberAve(ifstream &inFile, int &count, int playerArray[], double averageArray[]);
void bubbleSort(int playerArray[], int count);

//global constant
const int SIZE = 50;

int main()
{
    
    int playerArray[SIZE];
    double averageArray[SIZE];
    ifstream inFile;
    int count;
    
    //function call to open file
    openFile(inFile);
    
//  displayNumberAve(inFile, count, playerArray, averageArray);
    
//  selectSort(playerArray, count);
    bubbleSort(playerArray, count);
    
    cout << "Sorted array below" << endl;
    
    displayNumberAve(inFile, count, playerArray, averageArray);

    return 0;
} // closes int main

/***********************************
//openFile
//function to open and test file
***********************************/
void openFile(ifstream &inFile)
{
    inFile.open("battingInfo.txt");
    
    if(!inFile)
    {
        cout << "File not found, dummy" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }//closes if

    inFile.close();
} // closes function


/***********************************
//displayNumberAve
//displays array data in table
***********************************/
void displayNumberAve(ifstream &inFile, int &count, int playerArray[], double averageArray[])    
{
        inFile.open("battingInfo.txt");  //why is this refusing to show the file data unless i put this here?
        
        cout << "Player    Batting Average" << endl;
        if(inFile.is_open())
        {
        while(!inFile.eof())
        {
            inFile >> playerArray[count];
            inFile >> averageArray[count];
            cout << setw(2) << left << playerArray[count] << right << setw(13) << averageArray[count] << endl;
                
        }//closes while
        }//closes if
}//closes function

/******************************************
//bubbleSort
//sort the plater array using bubble sort
******************************************/
void bubbleSort(int playerArray[], int count)
{
    int maxElement;
    int index;
    int temp;
    int count;
    for (maxElement = count - 1; maxElement > 0; maxElement--)
    {
        for (index = 0; index < maxElement; index++)
        {
            if (playerArray[index] > playerArray[index + 1])
            {
                swap(playerArray[index] , playerArray[index + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
    
}//closes void
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: An array of files or a file of arrays?

Comment: @Thomas Matthews I have a file with some data in it, I am opening the file, pulling the data and putting it into an array.

Answer (score 0):

Your `displayNumberAve` should display the content of your `playerArray`.

Instead, it reads the content of the file `"battingInfo.txt"` into that array, and displays that.

Comment: So youre saying I should create a new function for display and remove the cout from displayNumberAve and put it into its own display function?

Comment: I created a display function, and moved the cout there instead... but now its only displaying the last element from the array

Comment: @ShadyForever could you please update the code in your question? I don't know what you've changed